# pg_dump not excluding table data

Tags: postgresql

I'm having difficulty making the `--exclude-table-data` option actually exclude the contents of my table. the `cache_data` table still gets exported. Any ideas?

`pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 11.11`:

```
pg_dump --verbose --clean --no-owner --no-acl \
  -f /tmp/db-dump.sql \
  --exclude-table '*.test*' \
  --exclude-table-data '*.cache' \
  --exclude-table-data '*.cache_data' \
  --exclude-table-data 'public.cache_data' \
  --exclude-table-data 'cache_data' \
  --exclude-table-data '*.cache_*'
```

I have tried every combination of these table names, and I still get a 2.6GB file with this in the ourput log...

```
pg_dump: processing data for table "public.cache_data"
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "public.cache_data"
```

Comment: On what OS are you doing this?  (/me asks after seeing this: https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2502011 )

Comment: (Ubuntu 11.11-1.pgdg18.04+1)

Comment: I was trying to reproduce thin on a Mac using  pg_dump version 13.3 but did not see anything wrong in `--exclude-table-data`.

Comment: What happens if you do: `-t public.cache_data --exclude-table-data 'public.cache_data'`?